# derivative of position vector is perpendicular to position vector

Tags: calculus

$\Large \vec{r}(s) = x(s)~\hat{\text{i}} + y(s)~\hat{\text{j}} + z(s)~\hat{\text{k}}$

$\Large \frac{\vec{r}(s)}{ds} = \frac{dx(s)}{ds}~\hat{\text{i}} + \frac{dy(s)}{ds}~\hat{\text{j}} + \frac{dz(s)}{ds}~\hat{\text{k}}$

$\Large \vec{r}(s)\cdot \frac{\vec{r}(s)}{ds} = (x \frac{dx}{ds}) + (y \frac{dy}{ds}) + (z \frac{dz}{ds})$

how to show that the dot product equals zero to prove that that $\vec{r}(s)$ is perpendicular to $\frac{\vec{r}(s)}{ds}$ as every good tangent vector should be?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not true that the tangent vector is perpendicular to the point of the curve.

Comment: take a look at answer... see anything wrong with it?  i'm wondering why its different.

Comment: This is true we the curve is parameterized by arc length.   That is  $\|\frac {dr}{ds}\| = 1.$  But not true in the case of a general parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For a particle moving from the origin along the $x$-axis we might have
$$r=si.$$

Then $\frac{dr}{ds}=i$ is parallel to $r$.

Comment: That's true, but it only proves it if $\vec{R}(s) = s~\hat{\text{i}}$. What if $\vec{R}(s)$  is any function of parameter s?

Comment: It is just an example to show that the perpendicular result is not true in general.

Comment: that's interesting...  could you take a look at my answer below and check it... there's something i'm not understanding...  maybe its only parallel if r is a constant and not a function s?

Comment: You are looking at the case where $r$ has constant length. The point is therefore moving in a circle about O in this case  the velocity and position vector are perpendicular.

Comment: so that would be the case where the function is a circle?

Comment: The point is moving in a circle - which particular function are you referring to?

Comment: I guess that would be $\vec{R}(u) = (\cos u)\hat{i} + (\sin u)\hat{\text{j}}$.  length is always 1 as it travels around circle.

Comment: and $\vec{R}(u) \cdot \vec{R}(u) = \begin{Vmatrix}R\end{Vmatrix}^2$ so i guess it makes sense that its constant length...

Comment: linear motion (derivative is parallel) vs. circular motion (derivative is perpendicular).... thanks.  i think i understand it now.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

the dot product of a vector $\vec{R}(u)$ with itself is equal to some constant k:

$$\vec{R}(u) \cdot \vec{R}(u)=k$$

take derivative of both sides.

$$\frac{d}{du}\bigg(\vec{R}(u) \cdot \vec{R}(u)\bigg)=\frac{d}{du}k$$

apply product rule of differentiation

$$\bigg(\vec{R}~'(u) \cdot \vec{R}(u)\bigg)+ \bigg(\vec{R}(u)\cdot\vec{R}~'(u)\bigg)= 0$$

$$\bigg(\vec{R}~'(u) \cdot \vec{R}(u)\bigg)+ \bigg(\vec{R}~'(u)\cdot\vec{R}(u)\bigg)= 0$$

$$2\bigg(\vec{R}~'(u) \cdot \vec{R}(u)\bigg) = 0$$

$$\vec{R}~'(u) \cdot \vec{R}(u) = 0$$

therefore: $R(u)~ \bot~R~'(u)$